# How can I open an .xsc file?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to read an .xsc file, but I'm not sure what program to use to open it with, I so I googled and everywhere it's telling me I can just use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, which I have but when I tried to open it with that, it gave me an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

XSC files are created by the Dataset Designer tool in Visual Studio. They should be able to open with `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional`. Check out [here](http://www.fileinfo.com/software/microsoft/visual_studio).

You can also open it in `FileViewPro`, see [here](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/file-extensions/file-extension-xsc/).